# javafx How to get specific tabvleview cell index?

Tags: javafx, tableview, cell

i have create a TableView with Columns and fill it with my sql database table data.
my qz is : 
when i change the cell value in column 0 to XXX i want to cell value in column 1 to change with YYYY value

how can i get the cell 1 index to insert the new value after edit commit cell 0 >?

Comment: A `TableView`, when used properly, is simply a _view_ of the model. If you want a change in a property of an item to cause an update to a different property of the same or different item then implement that in the model. Assuming everything has been properly configured, the change in the model will be automatically reflected in the `TableView`. If you're having trouble with this please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar "problem".

```
TablePosition pos = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0);
int row = pos.getRow();
int col = pos.getColumn();

TableColumn column = pos.getTableColumn();
Object o = column.getCellData(row); //getting the Value from the specific Cell
```

I used this method, after double clicking a cell. You have to modfiy this solution that it fits to your problem, but it should help you.

To edit the specific cell i used the method `setCellFactory` from the TableColumn class.

```
column.setCellFactory(factory -> new TableCell<ObservableList<Object>, Object>() {

  @Override
  protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {

    //Do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

At least at the end and after a week of searching for an answer, I found a solution and it is:

```
TablePosition TPOS = (TablePosition) table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(5);
    int rowIndex = TPOS.getRow();
    int colIndex = TPOS.getColumn();
    TableColumn COLP = (TableColumn) table.getColumns().get(5);
TableCell cell = (TableCell)table.queryAccessibleAttribute(AccessibleAttribute.CELL_AT_ROW_COLUMN,rowIndex,colIndex);
cell.setText(String.valueOf(getPrice()));
```

// getPrice() is the return method to find the price of edited item cell value

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Not only do you assume the existance of at least 6 selected cells, you also assume that there is a cell for the column you want to edit which is not guaranteed in a virtualized control like `TableView`. Moreover modifying a cell won't result in the data being stored. As soon as you scroll the cell in question out of the viewport and back, the old value returns. Furthermore columns can be reordered by the user resulting in more complications... You need to modify the data in the item; modifying the cell won't do the trick.